# Iterate over items in loop with a range based on property in item

Tags: ansible

I have the following json object:

```json
"python_tasks": [
    {
        "name": "Test 1",
        "instances": 2,
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "instances": 3,
    }
]
```

I am reading that object into the following Ansible task

```yaml
- name: Display variables
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }} {{item.index}}"
  with_items: "{{ python_tasks }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
  loop: "{{ range(item.instances|int) | list }}"
```

I am expecting to be able to output 2 instances of Test1 and 3 instances of Test 2. But I receive an `item is undefined` error. Any help would be much appreciated, as I have looked through the Ansible docs and I cannot see how it can be achieved.

Comment: `item` is defined once you are inside a loop. `loop` and `with_item` are (tl;dr) doing the same thing, are mutually exclusive and are in total contradiction in the above example. Please take the time to read in depth [ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html). As your question is written, it is hard to understand what you are trying to do exactly. Please read [ask] paying a particular attention to the [mre] section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess. Please edit your question and add more details if it does not fit your needs.

Example file structure

```
$ tree
.
├── playbook.yml
└── play_test.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

In `play_test.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Play test
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg:
      - "I'm playing test {{ my_python_test.name }}"
      - "This is iteration {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, my_python_test.instances | int) }}"
```

In `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Play my tests
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    python_tasks:
      - name: Test 1
        instances: 2
      - name: Test 2
        instances: 3

  tasks:
    - name: Play python test instances
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: play_test.yml
      loop: "{{ python_tasks }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: my_python_test
```

Test run:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Play my tests] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Play python test instances] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /tmp/toto/play_test.yml for localhost => (item={'name': 'Test 1', 'instances': 2})
included: /tmp/toto/play_test.yml for localhost => (item={'name': 'Test 2', 'instances': 3})

TASK [Play test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm playing test Test 1",
        "This is iteration 0"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm playing test Test 1",
        "This is iteration 1"
    ]
}

TASK [Play test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm playing test Test 2",
        "This is iteration 0"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm playing test Test 2",
        "This is iteration 1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm playing test Test 2",
        "This is iteration 2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "name: {{ item.1 }} iteration: {{ item.0 }}"
      loop: |
        {% filter from_yaml %}
        {% for i in python_tasks %}
        {% for j in range(i.instances) %}
        - [{{ j }}, {{ i.name }}]
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfilter %}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'name: Test 1 iteration: 0'
  msg: 'name: Test 1 iteration: 1'
  msg: 'name: Test 2 iteration: 0'
  msg: 'name: Test 2 iteration: 1'
  msg: 'name: Test 2 iteration: 2'
```

---

Optionally, create the ranges

```yaml
  python_tasks_update: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in python_tasks %}
    - range: {{ range(i.instances) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  python_tasks_update:
    - range: [0, 1]
    - range: [0, 1, 2]
```

and update the list

```yaml
  python_tasks_range: "{{ python_tasks|
                          zip(python_tasks_update)|
                          map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  python_tasks_range:
    - instances: 2
      name: Test 1
      range: [0, 1]
    - instances: 3
      name: Test 2
      range: [0, 1, 2]
```

Then iterate with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "name: {{ item.0.name }} iteration: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ python_tasks_range|subelements('range') }}"
```

gives (abridged) the same result

```yaml
  msg: 'name: Test 1 iteration: 0'
  msg: 'name: Test 1 iteration: 1'
  msg: 'name: Test 2 iteration: 0'
  msg: 'name: Test 2 iteration: 1'
  msg: 'name: Test 2 iteration: 2'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    python_tasks:
      - {instances: 2, name: Test 1}
      - {instances: 3, name: Test 2}

    python_tasks_update: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in python_tasks %}
      - range: {{ range(i.instances) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    python_tasks_range: "{{ python_tasks|
                            zip(python_tasks_update)|
                            map('combine') }}"
      
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: python_tasks_update|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: python_tasks_range|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "name: {{ item.0.name }} iteration: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ python_tasks_range|subelements('range') }}"
```